# Grouping a dataframes by max and min integers from a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of a list of addresses organised this way:

```
    number          street          city            state    zip
0     1           Green Av          Evergreen       FL       33000
1     2           Green Av          Evergreen       FL       33000
2     4           Green Av          Evergreen       FL       33000
3     1           Red Av            Evergreen       FL       33000
4     2           Red Av            Evergreen       FL       33000
5     5           Red Av            Evergreen       FL       33000
6     3           Main St           Evergreen       FL       33000
7     5           Main St           Evergreen       FL       33000
8     8           Main St           Evergreen       FL       33000
```

I am looking for a way to obtain the min and max house number for every street in a different df such as:

```
      street            city            state    zip       min_house#   max_house#
0     Green Av          Evergreen       FL       33000       1          4
1     Red Av            Evergreen       FL       33000       1          5
2     Main St           Evergreen       FL       33000       3          8
```

How would I order the data using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `group by` with both min and max:

```
df = df.groupby('street').agg(['min','max'])
df.columns = [' '.join(col).strip() for col in df.columns.values]
cols = ['number min', 'number max', 'city min', 'state min', 'zip min']
df = df[cols]
df.rename(columns={'number min':'min', 'number max':'max', 'city min':'city', 
                  'state min':'state', 'zip min':'zip'},inplace=True)


df.reset_index(inplace=True)

     street  min  max       city state    zip
0  Green Av    1    4  Evergreen    FL  33000
1   Main St    3    8  Evergreen    FL  33000
2    Red Av    1    5  Evergreen    FL  33000
```